# Using DNS and DHCP from campus instead 192.168.* ? WRT54gs2

Tags: networking, wireless-router

So instead of using 192.168.* how can I have computers on my router use my school's 152.65.*? It'd be nice for sharing things around the place. I'm sorry if I should have found this through a search - all the answers that sort of went into what I was looking for all made sense but I'm just not sure a WRT54gs2 can do this as I'm not sure its software allows for such routing capabilities.

I sort of know how one would theoretically do this (I'm currently taking a networking class at school) but can I do this with a WRT-54gs2?

Thanks for any help and sorry if this the wrong place :/

Comment: All you need to do is ensure your router is plugged into the campus network, make sure it gets a DHCP address, then set DHCP forwarding to assign addresses from upstream. Then your gateway will be the router, and the campus network will sort the rest out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use one of your university's IP addresses, you'd need to be on their network, or at least have their network configured to support it. Your university has a class B network, so all the traffic for 152.65.[something] will be routed in the same direction by external networks. Only once it reaches network equipment owned by or at least closely associated with you university (e.g. owned by their ISP) can it be directed to more specific locations. The default assumption would be to direct it all towards your university's physical campus, but it could be split and directed to multiple places - for instance, if your university has multiple campuses. The bottom line is: your broadband connection will not receive traffic destined for any of your university's IPs, so you can assign yourself a 152.65.* IP all you like; you won't receive any traffic on it.

To further complicate things, your 192.168.* IP address is merely a local one that's specific to your home network; your internet connection will have it's own IP address assigned by your ISP, and the router uses [network address translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) to share that address between everything on your network. In theory, you could set up your router to assign addresses in the 152.65.0.0/16 network, but only devices on your network would know about them (external devices would still see the IP address assigned by your ISP) and it would cause all sorts of bother when you needed to route to somewhere that has a real 152.65.* address.

So, in short, just assigning yourself a 152.65.* IP won't magically put you on the university's network. There are ways to do this, though. A common way would be a [virtual private network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) (VPN). Your university may well have one set up already; if so, you simply tell your computer to connect to it. Instead of firing packets straight out into the internet, your computer will instead transmit them down an encrypted tunnel to a VPN endpoint on your university's network, which then sends them out into the internet. This endpoint will have a 152.65.* IP address, and thus your computer will, for all intents and purposes, appear to be on the university's network.

A simpler alternative that may be available if your university doesn't want to be bothered with a full-blown VPN (many aren't) is SSH tunneling. Open a terminal if you're on *nix, or PuTTY if you're on Windows, and do `ssh -D 1234 a.computer.at.your.uni.ac`. Then set your computer up to connect to the internet using a SOCKS proxy at 127.0.0.1, port 1234. This will do much the same thing as a VPN, with the exception that computers on your university's network won't be able to connect to you (it's possible to set that up with SSH, but that's another lesson). It will make your computer's transmissions appear to be coming from your university's network, and that is often enough if you're trying to access some resource (like online papers) that is only available to university users.

Comment: Hmmm thanks for the lesson that was quite informative. I'm relatively versed in the use of SSH and have been getting better with tunneling and so forth. I'll have to experiment a little more. Very very helpful post though - I'll take this as an answer as I'm not sure how much better we could get!